# regular expression to search and replace, starting after only n matches

Tags: regex, perl, awk

I want to search and replace a simple string starting only after so many matches on each line, for example:

s/ZZ/YY for n=2

```
xxxZZxxxxxxZZxxxxZZxZZxxxxZZ
xZZxxxZZxxZZxxZZxZZxxxZZxxx
...
```

into:

```
xxxZZxxxxxxZZxxxxxYYxxxxYY
xZZxxxZZxxYYxxYYxYYxxxYYxxx
...
```

In my problem there will always be an 'x' in between sequential "ZZ"s. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest an executable replacement string, which allows you to count the number of matches seen so far

This code demonstrates

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
  my $n = 0;
  s/(ZZ)/$n++ < 2 ? $1 : 'YY'/eg;
  print;
}

__DATA__
xxxZZxxxxxxZZxxxxZZxZZxxxxZZ
xZZxxxZZxxZZxxZZxZZxxxZZxxx
```

**output**

```
xxxZZxxxxxxZZxxxxYYxYYxxxxYY
xZZxxxZZxxYYxxYYxYYxxxYYxxx
```

Answer (score 3):

There are probably look-behind solutions, or a reverse-the-string-and-look-ahead-and-reverse-it-again solutions (and if there are, I'll upvote them), but I usually find solutions using `while` to be easier to discover, and arguably easier to read.

```
1 while $string =~ s/(ZZ.*ZZ.*)ZZ/$1YY/
```

That is, while the string contains three `ZZ` patterns, replace the 3rd one with `YY`.

As a general solution:

```
$expr = (quotemeta($pattern1) . ".*") x $n;
1 while $string =~ s/($expr)\Q$pattern2\E/$1$pattern2/;
```

Comment: Your "general" solution actually makes assumptions about its inputs. e.g., it fails for $pattern1="ZZ", $pattern2="ZZZ", and for $pattern1="ZZ", $pattern2="Z".

Comment: Even for small $n, that could be VERY VERY VERY slow. O(N**$n), I believe

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the simplest perl solution *should* be: `1 while s/ZZ/YY/3`, but perl does not accept that.  So do the same with `sed`:

```
sed ':a
  s/ZZ/YY/3
  ta'
```

Some implementations of `sed` allow this to be written more simply: `sed ':a; s/ZZ/YY/3; ta'`, and I believe it is fully portable to write: `sed -e :a -e s/ZZ/YY/3 -e ta`

Answer (score 1):

```
1 while $thisline=~s/((?:x*?ZZx*?){2}[xZY]*?)ZZ/$1YY/;
```

That is a solution for n=2.

You can just change the number there for other values of n.

Also, I optimized the substitution with lazy matching and by doing away with superfluous capturing.